# Laravel has many through

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, has-many-through

My table

```
products
  - id
  - name

product_variants
  - id
  - product_id
  - color_id

product_colors
  - id
  - hex
```

I wan't to have a relationship like this

```
Product::colors(); // get all the colors through variants
```

In my Product.php model I have

```
public function colors() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\ProductColor', 'App\Models\Product', 'id', 'id', 'product_id', 'product_color_id');
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

As a side note. In current laravel docs it gives the example of:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
```

Where I don't think the comments are correct. The local keys in my experience are before the foreign keys.

Comment: I think you have params in the wrong order within your function.

`return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\ProductColor', 'App\Models\Product', 'product_id', 'product_color_id','id', 'id');`

Comment: Have you tried it with `... 'product_id', 'product_color_id', 'id', 'id')`? if the docs suggest to do it that way, you should probably do it that way, even if you disagree with it. Also, you can omit `'id', 'id'` if you're using `id` columns in your tables; these params are optional, and if you're using the same as the default, you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your database seems that the relation from color to product is a many to many, and the code should be 
Product Model:

```php
public function colors(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ProductColor', 'product_variants', 'product_id', 'id')->withPivot('id');
}
```

ProductColors Model:

```php
public function products(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_variants', 'id', 'product_id')->withPivot('id');
}
```

Or, if you want more flexibility, create a ProductVariant Model, and use a hasMany relation on Product and ProductColor and inside ProductVariant use two belongsTo, to Product and to ProductColor